# unable to copy cropped image (opencv Mat) into Bitmap

Tags: android, opencv

I have an input image sourceMat.

Crop a 40x40 roi located at (10,10):

```
Mat roi = sourceMat.submat(10, 50, 10, 50);
```

Create a Bitmap of size 40x40:

```
Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(40, 40, thumbnail.getConfig());
```

Convert the Mat to Bitmap and set in ImageView:

```
Utils.matToBitmap(roi, tempBitmap);
imageView.setImageBitmap(tempBitmap );
```

Instead of showing the cropped image, it shows the whole original image downscaled into a 40x40 bitmap.

I am working with openCVLibrary320 and android sdk version 25

Comment: Need to crop a portion from an ImageMat i.e sourceMat and show it on an imageView.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Antonio and working on openCVLibrary320 and android sdk version 25.

Comment: I would also try `Bitmap.createBitmap(40, 40, RGB_565);` What is `thumbnail` by the way?

Comment: You should try with `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` instead of `thumbnail.GetConfig()`

Comment: thanks guys...it works, code is correct minor changes... @RickM.@Antonio.

Comment: @harshbangari you should add the changes as an answer for future users

Comment: @RickM. There will be no change in code as it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(40, 40, thumbnail.getConfig());
```

With either one of these:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(40, 40, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Bitmap.createBitmap(40, 40, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html).

Answer (score -1):

Code is working fine and there will be small change in code.

```
  private void showDialog(File pictureFile) {
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.image_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Image");
    // find the imageview and draw it!
    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
    Bitmap thumbnail;
    try {
        thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(pictureFile));
        cropImage(image, thumbnail);
//            Imgproc.threshold(tmp, tmp, 60, 100, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
//            Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, image1);
//            Imgproc.threshold(tmp, tmp, 1, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
        //using floodfill and watershed to remove noise
//            Mat mask = new Mat(tmp.rows() + 2, tmp.cols() + 2, CvType.CV_8UC1);
//            Imgproc.floodFill(tmp, mask, new Point(tmp.cols() - 10, 10), new Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255));
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}

private void cropImage(ImageView image, Bitmap thumbnail) {
    Mat src = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(thumbnail, src);
    //converts mat color
    Imgproc.cvtColor(src, src, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR);
    Rect roi = new Rect(40, 100, 100, 120);
    Mat cropped = new Mat(src, roi);
    Bitmap tempBmp1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 120, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(cropped, tempBmp1);
    image.setImageBitmap(tempBmp1);
}
```

Comment: Can you develop on this? Something must have changed from when it was not working to the moment it started working. This answer/question is not going to help anybody like that!